# Lo-Dash - help me understand why _.pick doesn't work the way I expect

Tags: javascript, lodash

This works:

```
MyCollection.prototype.select = function (properties) {
   var self = this;

   return {
      where: function (conditions) {
         return _.chain(self.arrayOfObjects)
           .where(conditions)
           .map(function (result) {
              return _.pick(result, properties);
           })
           .value();
      }
   };
};
```

It allows me to query my collection like so:

```
var people = collection
             .select(['id', 'firstName'])
             .where({lastName: 'Mars', city: 'Chicago'});
```

I expected to be able to write the code like this, though:

```
MyCollection.prototype.select = function (properties) {
   var self = this;

   return {
      where: function (conditions) {
         return _.chain(self.arrayOfObjects)
           .where(conditions)
           .pick(properties);
           .value();
      }
   };
};
```

Lo-Dash documentation specifies the `_.pick` callback as "[callback] (Function|…string|string[]): The function called per iteration or property names to pick, specified as individual property names or arrays of property names."  That led me to believe I could just supply the properties array, which would be applied to each item in `arrayOfObjects` that meets the conditions.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://lodash.com/docs#pick

It expects an `Object` as the first parameter, you're giving it an `Array`.

```
Arguments

1. object (Object): The source object.
2. ...
3. ...
```

I think this is the best you can do:

```
MyCollection.prototype.select = function (properties) {
   var self = this;

   return {
      where: function (conditions) {
         return _.chain(self.arrayOfObjects)
           .where(conditions)
           .map(_.partialRight(_.pick, properties))
           .value();
      }
   };
};
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was mistakenly thinking that _.pick would iterate over the array elements in the chaining context.

Comment: It seems strange to me also. So many other lodash functions iterate over array elements when chaining.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because `_.pick` expects an object, not a collection which is being passed through from the `where` function in your chain.